# Dealing with plm for panel regression models

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I'm dealing with panel data to study how macroeconomics indicators influence life insurance market with R-studio, but I'm not very familiar with panel regression, in particular with diagnostic tests to choose the right model.
I'm using `plm` package for the analysis according to the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf), [this documentation written by the authors](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plmPackage.html) and [another paper](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eotorres/Panel101R.pdf) by Princeton University's Data and Statistical Services website.

I have some doubts about the steps to follow to choose one between the pooling model, the within (FE) and the random (RE) model, using only individual or time effects or both (twoways).
Below I illustrate the code that I made with the comments for each step, so that you can correct me in case there were errors.
Before, I fitted a pooling model and three within models, each with a different effect (individual, time and twoways). Then I did a test for individual and or time effects using the `pFtest` function comparing the pooling model with each of the three fixed effect models, to see if it is better to use the first one or if there are individual and / or time effects in the data.

```
mod1 <- life_premium ~ gdp + birth_rate + eurozone + 
          perc_pens_oldage + age_pension + empl_rate

# Pooling ####

pooling <- plm(mod1, data = df_panel, index = c("country", 
                "year"), model = "pooling")
summary(pooling)
vif(pooling)


# Fixed ####

fixed1 <- plm(mod1, data = df_panel, index = c("country", "year"), 
               model = "within", effect = "individual")
summary(fixed1)

fixed2 <- plm(mod1, data = df_panel, index = c("country", "year"), 
  model = "within", effect = "time")
summary(fixed2)

fixed3 <- plm(mod1, data = df_panel, index = c("country", "year"), 
           model = "within", effect = "twoways")
summary(fixed3)

# Test for individual and/or time effects (p-value > 0.05 --->  pooling) ####
pFtest(fixed1, pooling)
pFtest(fixed2, pooling)
pFtest(fixed3, pooling)
```

In this step I obtained that there is the presence of individual effects, but not time, but when I test with the fixed3 model, the null is rejected and therefore the test also suggests using the twoways model.
At this point my doubt is whether it is worth considering only the model with individual effects or also the twoways model.
The next step was to create three other random models with the three different effects and compare them with the within models through the `phtest` function.

```
# Random ####

random1 <- plm(mod1, data = df_panel, index = c("country", 
            "year"), model = "random", effect = "individual")
summary(random1)

random2 <- plm(mod1, data = df_panel, index = c("country", 
            "year"), model = "random", effect = "time")
summary(random2)

random3 <- plm(mod1, data = df_panel, index = c("country", 
               "year"), model = "random", effect = "twoways")
summary(random3)



# Hausman test confrondo fixed e random (p-value < 0.05 ---> fixed) ####

phtest(fixed1, random1)
phtest(fixed1, random2)
phtest(fixed1, random3)
phtest(fixed2, random1)
phtest(fixed2, random2)
phtest(fixed2, random3)
phtest(fixed3, random1)
phtest(fixed3, random2)
phtest(fixed3, random3)
```

Also in this case I have doubts if it's convenient to fit all three random models or only those with the effects that have passed the pFtest (ie not to consider random2 and possibly also the twoways).

Finally, I proceed with the tests of serial correlation (using `pbgtest`) and for cross-sectional dependence (`pcdtest`) on the model that passes the Hausman test (random with individual effects).

```
# Test of serial correlation (p-value < 0.05 ---> serial correlation)
pbgtest(random1)

# Test for cross-sectional dependence (p-value < 0.05 ---> cross-sectional dependence) ####
pcdtest(random1)
```

About these two tests I have many doubts:
With `pcdtest`, am I also testing heteroskedasticity or only cross-sectional dependence? What should I do if the model does not pass one of the two tests or both? In which cases should I estimate the robust covarance matrix? Is there a more efficient way to perform analysis using less code?

Sorry for too many questions and for the long message, I hope someone can solve my doubts.